# Plaid webhook must be a non-empty string URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, plaid

I'm calling the https://plaid.com/docs/api/tokens/#linktokencreate endpoint using the plaid-python libraries. When I create a link token request.

LinkTokenCreateRequest:

```
{'client_name': 'MYCLIENTNAME', 'country_codes': ['US'], 'language': 'en', 'products': ['auth', 'transactions'], 'user': {'client_user_id': 'XXXXXXXXXX'}, 'webhook': '/webhooks/091e07ab'}
```

The plaid response is:

```
{
"display_message": null,
"documentation_url": "https://plaid.com/docs/#create-link-token",
"error_code": "INVALID_FIELD",
"error_message": "webhook must be a non-empty string URL",
"error_type": "INVALID_REQUEST",
"request_id": "E************p",
"suggested_action": null
}
```

The request works if I leave out the webhook parameter. Here's the code:

```
webhook_url = f"/webhooks/{user_hook_id}"
logger.info(f"webhook_url = {webhook_url}")
api_client = create_plaid_client()
client = plaid_api.PlaidApi(api_client)
token_request = LinkTokenCreateRequest( 
    products=[Products('auth'), Products('transactions')],
    webhook=webhook_url,
    client_name=client_name,
            country_codes=[CountryCode('US')],
            language='en',
            user=LinkTokenCreateRequestUser(
                client_user_id=user_hook_id
            )
        )
        logger.info(f"token_request = {token_request}")
        # create link token
        token_response = client.link_token_create(token_request)
        token = token_response['link_token']
```

I've also tried with the full hostname and uri and both produce the same error. What is wrong with the request?

**UPDATE 1:**

I ran the test again and here's the output. One thing I noticed this time with the webhook in the token_request is it looks to be formatted incorrectly. I'm calling LinkTokenCreateRequest like so:

```
token_request = LinkTokenCreateRequest( 
    products=[Products('auth'), Products('transactions')],
    webhook=webhook_url,
    client_name=client_name,
            country_codes=[CountryCode('US')],
            language='en',
            user=LinkTokenCreateRequestUser(
                client_user_id=user_hook_id
            )
        )
```

And the output for the call is below. You can see the webhook is generated with an empty string and then the webhook I provided.

```
[INFO]  2021-11-03T22:52:36.263Z    ba0ad99b-76bd-42bf-b096-ca3e75b764dc    webhook_url =  https://b4234etcA3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/webhooks/64a0f8d03754
[INFO]  2021-11-03T22:52:36.429Z    ba0ad99b-76bd-42bf-b096-ca3e75b764dc    token_request = {'client_name': 'Test',
 'country_codes': ['US'],
 'language': 'en',
 'products': ['auth', 'transactions'],
 'user': {'client_user_id': '64a0f8d03754'},
 'webhook': ' '
            'https://b4234etcA3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/webhooks/64a0f8d03754'}

2021-11-03T15:52:36.816-07:00            [ERROR] ApiException: (400)
            Reason: Bad Request
            HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Server': 'nginx', 'Date': 'Wed, 03 Nov 2021 22:52:36 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '289', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'plaid-version': '2020-09-14'})
            HTTP response body: {
                "display_message": null,
                "documentation_url": "https://plaid.com/docs/#create-link-token",
                "error_code": "INVALID_FIELD",
                "error_message": "webhook must be a non-empty string URL",
                "error_type": "INVALID_REQUEST",
                "request_id": "FrPnbQEDoQgI4f6",
                "suggested_action": null
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webhook parameter needs to include the entire webhook endpoint URI, including the https:// part, in the request.

Comment: I tried that also, same result. I mention that at the bottom of the issue

Comment: Can you update your question to show the exact request and response for the request where you tried that?

Comment: Hi Alex, The LinkTokenCreateRequest in my question is a print out of the line `logger.info(f"token_request = {token_request}")` and the plaid response is from the logged response from plaid. I'm trying the request against the sandbox environment. Thanks again for any help you can provide.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify -- I'd be looking for the exact request and response for a call where the `webhook` parameter is set correctly so that we can double-check that the `webhook` parameter you're passing doesn't have any problems (because the error code indicates a problem with the webhook parameter).

Comment: Please see update 1

Comment: Hm, what's up with the pair of empty single quotes before the webhook URL in the request? That seems like malformatting and potentially the cause of your issue.

Comment: I agree, but that’s what is produced by the LinkTokenCreateRequest object

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the value of `webhook_url`, but the sample code doesn't show where webhook_url is being set. What happens if you hard-code 'https://b4234etcA3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/webhooks/64a0f8d03754' as the value of the webhook instead of using the webhook_url variable?

Comment: webhook_url gets set just before like so: 
`webhook_url = f"{url}/webhooks/{user_hook_id}"` I log the value of webhook_url `[INFO]  2021-11-03T22:52:36.263Z    ba0ad99b-76bd-42bf-b096-ca3e75b764dc    webhook_url =  https://b4234etcA3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/webhooks/64a0f8d03754`. When I try it with the hard coded value in the LinkTokenCreateRequest it does appear to work. Which means there must be some hidden character in the {url} which comes from the env even though its not shown when the webhook_url is logged. I will look into this further thank you for your help.

Comment: The url variable is set in the environment and had a leading space which appears to cause the the LinkTokenCreateRequest to set it like so:
```'webhook': ' '
            'https://b4234etcA3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/webhooks/64a0f8d03754'``` 
Removing the leading space in the url fixes the issue.